# how to change toolbar icon color in Xamarin.Forms ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

It works for Android but in ios the toolbar icon is coming in a monochrome color. How to show them in the original icon image color ? Also I need to change the icon color dynamically based in the core source in xamarin.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create entry in the Assets catalog and set RenderAs to 'Original'.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you please give some code example ?

Comment: This is not done through the code. Check what is asset catalog and you should understand it.